# CompiledToAssembly RegEx slower than on-the-fly RegEx

Tags: .net, regex

We've compiled the following RegEx to a DLL using `CompileToAssembly`:

```
@".*DCL\s+([\w]+)\s+([\w\(\) \t\"",']+)"
```

The performance is about a factor of 5 to 10 slower than using the static `Regex.Matches` call. Note that we call `Regex.Matches` about 40K times for various text sizes.

We use the following options:

```
RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
```

What are we doing wrong? Shouldn't we have some kind of performance boost, preventing the application from re-creating the RegEx internals each time?

Our code looked/looks like this:

```
// Static calls:
foreach(var text in texts)
{
    foreach(var match in Regex.Matches(text, _patternAsString, _options)
        ...
}

// New with CompiledToAssembly:
var dclRegEx = new DclRegEx();
foreach(var text in texts)
{
    foreach(var match in dclRegEx.Matches(text))
        ...
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are not making a new instance of the compiled SentencePattern object on every call, can you show some code on how are you using it?

Comment: Could you compare that with a regex compiled on the fly? ie with `var dclRegEx = new Regex(@"your pattern", RegexOptions.Compiled | yourOtherOptions);`

Comment: By the way that regex *cannot* be optimal, the `.*` bit forces a lot of backtracking.

Comment: Check the .NET Framework versions in the assemblies. Try building the assembly that contains the compiled regular expressions on a system that has .NET Framework 4 instead of later versions installed. See [more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ek5zak6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Judging by what is written on that MSDN page, you have to use a static `Regex.Matches` as a workaround.

Comment: Did you finally come to some conclusion?